# Different events based on number of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling to get something to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/CreativeAU/ys12ed05/

```
warningbutton.onclick = function buttonClicks() {
count += 1;
if (count > 1) {
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.au";
}
else {
warningbutton.onclick = function() {warningpopup.style.display = "block";}
}};
```

---

**What I'm currently trying to do**

The first time a user clicks 'Go To Page 2', a warning popup will appear. Once they close the warning and click the button again - it will take them to Page 2.

Right now:

- Nothing happens on the first button click.
- On the second click, and every button click after = the warning popup appears.

---

**Ideally what I want**

When a user arrives to a page (let's call it Page1), I want them to have to have clicked Box 1 OR Box 2 at least once - before clicking the 'Go To Page 2' button. If they haven't - then a 'warning popup' will appear over the screen telling them that they need to. I have very little idea how to code this using other divs.

---

If anyone is able to help me solve ***'Ideally what I want'*** that would be awesome, but otherwise I will settle for what ***'I'm currently trying to do'***.

I've set it all up on the JsFiddle page just so you can visualise what I'm after.

Comment: You're not new to Java. You're new to Javascript.

Comment: You can use a radio button and then click on submit button with required attribute. Is this what you need?

Comment: can we use Jquery?

Comment: `Nothing happens on the first button click` I wouldn't say so. Something happens: your console says `count is undefined`. You're trying to increment an undefined value (count), you need to initialize it first (var count = 0). This crashes your script, _then_ nothing happens.

Comment: You're setting the href when `count > 1` and you expect a link on the first click? I would expect `count == 1`

Comment: nearly got it for you

Comment: i added an answer with the working you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does what you want i think. 
the link to google wont work, but this is because of stackoverflow.

```js
var counter = 0;
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#first').click(function(){
    counter++
   });
   $('#second').click(function(){
    counter++
   });
   $('#next-page').click(function(){
    if (counter >= 1) {
     window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.au";
    }else{
     $('#warning-popup').css("display", "block");
    }
   });
   $('#warning-popup').click(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
   }); 
  });
```

```css
#wrapper {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#first, #second, #next-page {
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 125px;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #FFF;
 margin: 10px;
}

#first, #second {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #189a3d;
 width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
}

#next-page {
 display: block;
 background-color: #2e82d0;
 width: 270px;
 height: 125px;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 25px;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #FFF;
}

#close {
    color: orange;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
 text-decoration: underline;
 margin-top: -0.35em; 
}#wrapper {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#first, #second, #next-page {
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 125px;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #FFF;
 margin: 10px;
}

#first, #second {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #189a3d;
 width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
}

#next-page {
 display: block;
 background-color: #2e82d0;
 width: 270px;
 height: 125px;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 25px;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

   <div id="first">B1</div>
     <div id="second">B2</div>

   <div id="warning-popup" class="overlay">
       WARNING TEXT HERE
     </div>

     <div id="next-page">Go to Page 2</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you buddy :) Ran it locally and that worked perfectly ^ Legend. Have +1'd the comment though I'm brand new so..

Comment: haha np mate love to help! could you maybe also upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, showing the alert if clicked the first time, and redirecting to google after another click.

```
var count = 0;    
warningbutton.onclick = function buttonClicks() {
    count += 1;
    if (count > 1) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.au";
    }
    else {
        warningpopup.style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `else` code.

You bind a new event on click, but do not trigger a click. You simply need to change the `display` attribute of your warning pop-up, without binding it on the click event.

A simple fix:

```
if (count > 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.au";
}
else {
    warningpopup.style.display = "block";
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are basically registering a new function with the onclick event when the count is not greater than 1. solution should be

```
 warningbutton.onclick = function buttonClicks() {
count += 1;
console.log(count);
if (count > 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.au";
}
else {
 warningpopup.style.display = "block";
}};
```